# tar: extract single file to a directory without creating subfolders

Tags: tar

My goal is to get the `helm` binary from `helm-v2.5.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz` into my `/usr/local/bin` in as few steps as possible. The challenge is that the `.tar.gz` file contains the binary in a `linux-amd64` subdirectory.

So when I do this:

```
$ wget -P /tmp https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/helm-v2.5.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ tar -xzvf /tmp/helm-v2.5.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin linux-amd64/helm
```

I end up with `/usr/local/bin/linux-amd64/helm` instead of `/usr/local/bin/linux-amd64/helm`.

Is there a `tar` parameter I am missing or do I need to include some `mv` & cleanup steps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `--strip-components=NUMBER`:

```
--strip-components=NUMBER
          Strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction.
```

which means that your command should look like this:

```
tar -xzvf /tmp/helm-v2.5.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin --strip-components=1 linux-amd64/helm
```

Comment: Thanks. This removes the 'x' attribute so I have to run `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/helm` after that but it does the trick.

Comment: I improved the answer, so that it doesn't lose the file mode.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, piping `wget` straight into `tar`, and using the transform param.

```
wget -O- https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/helm-v2.5.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar --transform 's!linux-amd64!/usr/local/bin!' -Pxzf - linux-amd64/helm
```